# How to collapse a sub-section in tableau crosstab

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following pivot table:

[image]

Is there a way to collapse the "Type" section, so I only have three rows:

- Movie
- TV Episode
- Grand Total

Basically, I'd like to be able to expand each section by clicking into it. Otherwise I'll have thousands of values that would require tons of scrolling to view all.

Here is one example, but this seems overkill (creating buttons with actions) and not quite practical to do it quickly: http://www.thedataschool.co.uk/ben-davis/drill-hierarchies-tableau-website-style-navigation/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hierarchies will do what you are looking for. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.html#qs_hierarchies.html.

On your data source pane, drag the Title dimension and drop it on top of the Type dimension. This will then prompt you to give the hierarchy a title. Hierarchies allow you to drill up and down.

The classic example of a hierarchy is the way dates function. You can drill up and down from year to day.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to create a hierarchy with Measure Names?